# How does an electric motor work?

Tags: electromagnetism

At school, we have been working on how an AC electric motor works. I have pasted a photo on how the textbook explains it functioning, however I do not understand it completely.
[image]

The description of each frame is not necessary for my question. The photo and intuition I believe is.

My question is: On the fifth frame, wouldn’t the motor “lose” a turn before switching poles again and then rotating? I have also pasted an illustration of my idea below:

[image]

Continuation:

[image]

As the photo tries to illustrate, wouldn’t the electric motor “lose” a turn because at *6* the current flow changes from up to down, but north is already down?

I understand that an electric motor runs very fast (and thus difficult to observe and experiment), but I am taking each frame to frame to understand how it really works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that the frames in the illustration come in pairs. Frame 1 is the same as frame 4, except that the rotating electromagnet has been rotated through 180 degrees (and its polarity has been reversed as well). Similarly frame 2 is the same as frame 5, except that the rotating electromagnet has been rotated through 180 degrees. So if there were a frame 6 shown it would look the same as frame 3 i.e. the rotating electromagnet would be aligned with the poles of the permanent magnet (the stator) but would have no polarity. This is because the AC current running through the windings of the electromagnet (the armature) does not reverse instantaneously - there are two brief moments in each cycle when the current in the armature is zero. These instants happen between frames 2 and 4 (when the polarity of the lower pole of the electromagnet changes from N to S), and again between frame 5 and 1 (when the polarity of the lower pole of the electromagnet changes from S to N). This instant of zero current is what the unpolarised state in frame 3 represents. At this instant there is no force on the rotating electromagnet, but it continues to rotate because of its momentum.

Comment: Hi gandalf61. If I understood your answer, did you mean this: There are certain points such as 6 (the current switches direction but north is already there), but that moment is very brief? Thus you would just not notice it?

Comment: @SMK Not sure what you mean by "north is already there". The electromagnet only has north and south poles when current is flowing in the armature. At stage 3 and 6 there is no current in the armature so the electromagnet has no north or south poles - is is not magnetised at this instant.

Comment: Oh okay thank you